# QGIS 3.12 "Ballpark transform" shifted all the layers randomly on our project's due date!

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I am using QGIS for data processing on a hydraulic model in another software that uses shapefiles for its data. The coordinate system is:
ESRI:102740 - NAD_1983_StatePlane_Texas_South_Central_FIPS_4204_Feet
and for some reason, QGIS always says "unknown CRS" when I open a file in this system, and I have to set CRS again myself. Today, I'm realizing that QGIS shifted over half of our shapefiles by a completely random transformation! This is what it has to say for itself:

```
An alternative, ballpark-only transform was used when transforming coordinates between Unknown CRS: BOUNDCRS[SOURCECRS[PROJCRS["NAD83 / Texas South Ce… and ESRI:102740 - NAD_1983_StatePlane_Texas_South_Central_FIPS_4204_Feet. The results may not match those obtained by using the preferred operation:
+proj=pipeline +step +proj=unitconvert +xy_in=us-ft +xy_out=m +step +inv +proj=lcc +lat_0=27.8333333333333 +lon_0=-99 +lat_1=28.3833333333333 +lat_2=30.2833333333333 +x_0=600000 +y_0=3999999.99999999 +ellps=GRS80 +step +proj=hgridshift +grids=ethpgn.gsb +step +proj=lcc +lat_0=27.8333333333333 +lon_0=-99 +lat_1=28.3833333333333 +lat_2=30.2833333333333 +x_0=600000 +y_0=3999999.99998984 +ellps=GRS80 +step +proj=unitconvert +xy_in=m +xy_out=us-ft
**Possibly an incorrect choice of operation was made for transformations between these reference systems. Check the Project Properties and ensure that the selected transform operations are applicable over the whole extent of the current project.**
```

How do I undo this "possibly incorrect" transformation?

Comment: Try using the epsg code rather than the proprietary esri one.

Comment: Well the entire project has been in that coord sys, which QGIS does have available, it just won't recognize a shapefile in that system. I have no idea why an automatic "ballpark transformation" would even exist. Does anyone know how to undo it from that information provided?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there are various different projections that are known roughly as [South Texas Nad 83 Feet](http://epsg.io/?q=texas%20south%20nad83) including:

1. [EPSG:2279](http://epsg.io/2279) NAD83 / Texas South (ftUS)
2. [EPSG:3672](http://epsg.io/3672) NAD83(NSRS2007) / Texas South (ftUS)
3. [EPSG:2920](http://epsg.io/2920) NAD83(HARN) / Texas South (ftUS)
4. [EPSG:6586](http://epsg.io/6586) NAD83(2011) / Texas South (ftUS)

QGIS used to just pick one if it couldn't tell what you meant - now it warns you that something is going wrong.

So download the `.prj` file from the correct EPSG code and add that to all your shapefiles (if they really are all the same projection) and then QGIS will be happy.

Comment: Now that's bizarre, they all had a .prj from when they got assigned the coord sys in the other program (PCSWMM). arcmap had no beef with it. I DL'd the .prj and copied/renamed it to match my shapefiles and like you said no problem opening in QGIS. Looks like I'll need to write a script that does that for me.

Comment: I'm still left with the issue that while they are all in the right coord sys, half my shapefiles got 'ballpark transformed' by some random amount, and no longer line up with anything. You know how to undo the transformation from the info above? (+lat_0=27.8333333333333 +lon_0=-99 +lat_1 etc)

Comment: Perhaps discussion in this issue https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/34983 is helpful.

Comment: Nevermind, that didn't help, it says 'This layer appears to have no projection specification' using the .prj I downloaded from EPSG.